# java how to check whether file can be opened by default application without to open it

Tags: java, swing, awt

In my Swing application I have an action which opens a file with the system application

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
```

This action must be disabled when no application is registered for this file. I cann't understand how to get this information before the application has been launched (after that I get this information when an IOException is thrown).

Comment: If your application is not supposed to open all files , you could try using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html to restrict the files the application could open

Comment: @RanjitGopinathan Unfortunatelly my application is supposed to open all files (files are saved in our cloud, so I have no `JFileChooser` to use `FileFilter`).

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Windows + MacOS

Comment: Have you tried checking file associations in the registry on Windows: [Utilising a file association in a Java application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043029/utilising-a-file-association-in-a-java-application)? I'm not sure about MacOS.

Comment: On Mac OS X, scan the output of [`lsregister -dump`](http://krypted.com/mac-security/lsregister-associating-file-types-in-mac-os-x/).